# Getting 403 Forbidden Error While Accessing Google Chrome Web Store API

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-extension

We have a chrome extension in Google web store under my Google user id and I want to give API access to my colleagues (in the same organization). I am [following this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using_webstore_api/) but it is not allowing me to access API. Here is exactly what I did

1. Created a Google Cloud console project using the email id that is
   used to access the chrome store
2. Enabled Google Chrome Web Store API
3. Generated Oauth credentials as described in the link
4. Added my colleagues email address as test users under Oauth Consent section
5. Generated the "code" as described in the link using Colleague's Google ID
6. Successfully got the token by sending the curl request as described in the instructions above
7. Sent a curl API GET request using the token as shown below

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: $TOKEN"  \
-H "x-goog-api-version: 2" \
-H "Content-Length: 0" \
-H "Expect:" \
-X GET \
-v \
https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/ITEM_ID?projection=DRAFT
```

The response I get is this

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea on what I am missing here?

https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/ITEM_ID?projection=DRAFT

Answer (score 3):

The Authorization header is missing the token type: `Bearer`

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```